# Middle Mouse Click on Links To Open New Tab Only ASP C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, html

1) How would one detect that middle clicking the mouse wheel on links as opposed to right/left clicking?

2) Behavior should be new tab for middle mouse wheel click on links and reload in the same page if left click. (Same as Chrome).

3) ASP.Net, C# and the links are the first select link column within a gridview.
Gridview first column select links:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: By Asp.Net you mean Web Forms?

Comment: yes the website version not MVC

Answer (score 2):

In web forms actually you can use server side to detect this. You can do this:

```
private void mouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
    {    
        //Open new window
    }
    else
    {
        //Open on the same window
    }
}
```

But it's hard to open new window in server side I'm afraid. So it's better to use client side.

Comment: Not working in ASP.net since MouseEventArgs is for Windows Forms Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your JavaScript

```
function fixWhich(e) {
  if (!e.which && e.button) {
    if (e.button & 1) e.which = 1      // Left
    else if (e.button & 4) e.which = 2 // Middle
    else if (e.button & 2) e.which = 3 // Right
  }
}
```